# "ORA-00917: missing comma" & vbLf

Tags: oracle, ado.net

Below is my query which is created in .Net code for insertion in oracle table. I found other related articles but they are different and not answering this. I was creating below query using a datatable.

```
`Public Sub UpdateOracleRecordset(dtTable As DataTable)
    Dim sql As String = String.Empty
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    sql = "insert into " + dtTable.TableName + "("
    For Each dc As DataColumn In dtTable.Columns
        sql = sql + dc.ToString() + ","
    Next
    sql = sql.TrimEnd(",") + ")" + " select "
    Dim rowVal As String = String.Empty
    For Each dtRow As DataRow In dtTable.Rows
        For Each dc As DataColumn In dtTable.Columns
            rowVal = rowVal + dtRow(dc).ToString() + ","
        Next
        rowVal = rowVal.TrimEnd(",") 
    Next

    sql = sql + rowVal
    ExecuteSQL(sql)
End Sub`

"insert into CS_INV(LOANNO,CASENUMBER,INQ_TYPE,FUP_REASON,FUP_DATE,FUP_PROM,USERID,DATA_DAT,UNIT) values ( 5735985,103550709,399,58,9/24/2018 1:37:01 AM,9/25/2018 12:00:00 AM,Anurag,9/24/2018 1:37:08 AM,1 ) "
```

Comment: Search for "prepared statements" or "bind variables", then you should find the solution. You SQL string could be like `insert into CS_INV(LOANNO,CASENUMBER,INQ_TYPE,FUP_REASON,FUP_DATE,FUP_PROM,USERID,DATA_DAT,UNIT) values ( 5735985,103550709,399,58,:FUP_DATE,:FUP_PROM,Anurag,:DATA_DAT,1 )` or `insert into CS_INV(LOANNO,CASENUMBER,INQ_TYPE,FUP_REASON,FUP_DATE,FUP_PROM,USERID,DATA_DAT,UNIT) values ( 5735985,103550709,399,58,?,?,Anurag,?,1 )`

Comment: As of the error itself, numbers can be inserted that way, but dates and strings have to be enclosed into single quotes (also, dates should have a proper format mask along with the TO_DATE function, unless you use a date literal or are just lucky to match format with NLS settings). For the rest, have a look at the comment posted by Wernfried; I know nothing about "prepared statements".

Answer (score 0):

Wenfried is right and I used prepared statements which helped to resolve the issue

```
Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)
    conn.Open()

    Dim sql As String = String.Empty
    Dim sqlValues As String = String.Empty
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    sql = "insert into " + dtTable.TableName + "("
    For Each dc As DataColumn In dtTable.Columns
        sql = sql + dc.ToString() + ","
        sqlValues = sqlValues + ":" + dc.ToString() + ","
    Next
    sql = sql.TrimEnd(",") + ")" + " values ( " + sqlValues.TrimEnd(",") + ")"

    Dim commandText = sql
    Dim Command As New OracleCommand(sql, conn)
    For Each dtRow As DataRow In dtTable.Rows
        For Each dc As DataColumn In dtTable.Columns
            Command.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(dc.ToString(), dtRow(dc)))
        Next
    Next

    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
```